# WooCommerce - importing CSV with images located on another server - import gets stuck at 0%

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import

Situation:

Product supplier provided me with a CSV file containing all the item data, including professional images. Yay.

The image URLs all look like this: https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=nnnnnnn&c=nnnnnnn&h=nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn

Trying to import them into WooCommerce - import gets stuck.

Thinking it's the images, deleted the images column only. All products imported 100% fine. So the problem is definitely the images.

Trying to do a separate update, i.e. import just 2 columns "SKU" and "IMAGE" - import gets stuck.

Sanity check: deleted all but ONE line. Import gets stuck.

Found out that the WooCommerce Action Scheduler was running a cron job every minute. Changed it to 1/hour. No cron jobs running more often than 1/hour. Import still gets stuck.

Any advice on what to do in this situation? What else can I check?

Comment: Maybe try to use WPAllImport, with the WC extention. I have very good experience with it.

Comment: could check if the uploaded image file is exceeding maximum upload size for php and wordpress. also test with local images and from a different site.

Comment: @ Matts - the CSV is like 800K, so way below max file size, I have 4MB images that go in (manually) without a problem. But I even tried it with a 1-line, 8KB CSV, with the same result. Local images work, but it still takes a ridiculously long time - about 30 minutes for a 900-image import. Don't have another NetSuite site to test from :/